# Passing NSManagedObject or only one property?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an application where I pass a NSManagedObject with many (more 30) to UIViews.
I am doing it using `assign`.

I wonder if its is more expensive then passing a 2 or 3 properties (only the ones that the view needs) instead ?

I would love to get a clear explanation :).

Thanks
Shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to know if it more expensive to pass only the values of the NSManagedObject or the NSManagedObject itself.  Objects are stored in the heap memory and are referenced by other objects as a memory address (a byte or two).  It does not make duplicates of the object unless you tell it to.  So if you use "strong", "assign", "retain", etc. you are not adding much memory.  If you use "copy" then a new object is created and for the most part has everything in the original object copied as well.  That would be expensive in terms of memory.  So I think you're OK holding a reference to the NSManagedObject in each of the UIView without too much worry.

HTH